# I can't solve this problem that I have with Telegram API bots

Tags: java, api, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I keep receiving this errors .

```
Jun 22, 2022 12:13:10 PM org. apache. http. imp l . exec chain .Retry Exec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java . net. Socket Exception) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: Network is unreachable: no further information
Jun 22, 2022 12:13:11 PM org .apache .http .imp l .exec chain. Retry Exec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
Jun 22, 2022 12:13:32 PM org. apache. http. imp l .exec chain. Retry Exec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java. net. Socket Exception) caught when processing request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443: Network is unreachable: no further information
Jun 22, 2022 12:13:32 PM org. apache. http. imp l. exec chain. Retry Exec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbqhh.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just to use tor proxy:

```
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().put("proxySet", true);
        System.getProperties().put("socksProxyHost", 127.0.0.1);
        System.getProperties().put("socksProxyPort", 9050);
    }
}
```

But previously you should install tor service:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```